# Join not working properly

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2005

I am inserting value into the table like below

```
INSERT INTO p_leave_allocation_11122015(Mkey, Entry_Sr_no, Comp_mkey,FDepartment_Id,FModule_Id,Year, Emp_mkey, Emp_card_no, U_Datetime, Delete_Flag,Month12,PL_Days,)
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY p_leave_allocation.MKey) + 1643,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Entry_Sr_no) + 898, 
        Comp_mkey, FDepartment_Id, FModule_Id,
        '2016', Emp_mkey, Emp_card_no, U_Datetime,
        Delete_Flag, Month12, 0 
    FROM 
        p_leave_allocation lev 
    WHERE
        Emp_mst Emp 
    LEFT JOIN 
        p_leave_allocation AND Emp.status IN ('A','S') 
        AND YEAR(Emp.Date_Of_Joining) = '2015'
```

but I'm getting an error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Emp'.

What is wrong here ?

**UPDATE**

I tried like this but getting error as

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Code is:-

```
INSERT INTO p_leave_allocation_11122015(Mkey, Entry_Sr_no, Comp_mkey,FDepartment_Id,FModule_Id,Year, Emp_mkey, Emp_card_no, U_Datetime, Delete_Flag,Month12,PL_Days,)
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY p_leave_allocation.MKey) + 1643,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Entry_Sr_no) + 898, 
        Comp_mkey, FDepartment_Id, FModule_Id,
        '2016', Emp_mkey, Emp_card_no, U_Datetime,
        Delete_Flag, Month12, 0 
    FROM 
        p_leave_allocation lev LEFT JOIN  Emp_mst emp
    WHERE
       emp.Status in ('A','S')
     and 
   Year(emp.Date_Of_Joining) = '2015'
```

Comment: Format your question so that it is readable

Comment: @Amit is that the reason for downvote ?

Comment: It should be `SELECT ... FROM ... LEFT JOIN .... WHERE .....` you're mixing up the T-SQL syntax pretty badly - you should go look up the details of how to write a proper `SELECT` statement on SQL Server Books Online !

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks a lot, let me try and check

Comment: @marc_s: Sir, I tried, but it is not working. Getting error as `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.` now

Comment: Where is left joing condition as per table relation

Comment: @marc_s: Can you suggest me where I am wrong here and some online books, will be glad to learn that..! `INSERT INTO p_leave_allocation_11122015(Mkey, Entry_Sr_no, Comp_mkey,FDepartment_Id,FModule_Id,Year, Emp_mkey, Emp_card_no, U_Datetime, Delete_Flag,Month12,PL_Days)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BYp_leave_allocation.MKey) + 1643,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Entry_Sr_no) +898,Comp_mkey,FDepartment_Id,FModule_Id,'2016',Emp_mkey,Emp_card_no, U_Datetime,Delete_Flag, Month12, 0 FROMp_leave_allocation lev LEFT JOIN  Emp_mst emp WHERE emp.Status in ('A','S') and Year(emp.Date_Of_Joining) = '2015'`

Comment: Yes it was, but now that the question is improved, I removed it

Comment: @Amit: if it was just because, the code was not properly formatted you downvoted fine. But at the same time you should have told how to format the code, Sorry for being harsh.!! Thanks, happy learning.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `on` clause:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY p_leave_allocation.MKey) + 1643,  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Entry_Sr_no) + 898, 
    Comp_mkey, FDepartment_Id, FModule_Id,
    '2016', Emp_mkey, Emp_card_no, U_Datetime,
    Delete_Flag, Month12, 0 
FROM p_leave_allocation lev LEFT JOIN
     Emp_mst emp
     ON lev.?? = emp.??
-----^
WHERE emp.Status in ('A', 'S')  and 
      YEAR(emp.Date_Of_Joining) = '2015';
```

I don't know what the columns are for joining.  In the first query, you have a `WHERE` clause in the middle of the `FROM` clause`.  The`WHERE` clause goes afterwards.

Comment: getting error as `Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "p_leave_allocation.MKey" could not be bound.`